# Understanding rabbitMQ memory details

Tags: memory-usage, rabbitmq

I'm trying to analyze rabbitMQ memory issue. Sometimes the server will run out of memory when most of the queues are empty and there are very few messages pending.

What can I learn from this memory status snapshot ?
Especially, what does the binary reference represents?

[image: A memory status]

Comment: See https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory-use.html - which btw is the first hit I get when I google "rabbitmq memory".